# Ubuntu issues with desktop environments

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I got curious and tried out the GNOME shell desktop environment, but when I went back to Unity, I couldn't click anything, except the stuff in the side bar and the top bar, that was it, I even ran a few commands, uninstalled GNOME, and rebooted my computer numerous times.

Comment: You said "you went back Unity", does that mean you also uninstalled Gnome shell? Otherwise, did you uninstall Unity before switching to Gnome shell?

Comment: @TungTran He said he just loaded Unity, he kept GNOME.

Comment: No, he said he uninstalled Gnome and went back Unity. I missed that point at the first glance.

Comment: @TungTran I logged out and switched back to Unity from where we can choose the DE we want to use. Then I whent

Answer (score 0):

If you've uninstalled gnome already, and assuming from what you described it's bad enough that you can't run terminal from the unity desktop, log out or reboot your computer.  When the login screen comes up press CTRL+ALT+F1 and log in to TTY.  Then:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove gnome-shell
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Should have everything working again.

The --purge autoremove gnome-shell should work even though you've already removed the package.  If it doesn't you might need to reinstall gnome-shell again and --purge autoremove it again.

(Edited to simplify and include note)